# One big box contains three parallelly placed small boxes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to make the three small boxes inside a big box with `tikz`. The three small backs are placed side by side at the bottom of the bog box.

What I have tried so far is:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[block/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum width=0.4*\columnwidth, anchor=south}, font=\small]
    \node[block, text width=0.1*\columnwidth, align=left](acc) at (0,0){Accelerometer};
    \node[block, text width=0.1*\columnwidth, align=left](gyro) at (acc.east+0.1,0){Gyroscope};
    \node[block, text width=0.1*\columnwidth, align=left](mag) at (gyro.east+0.1,0){Magnetometer};
    \draw(0, 0)rectangle(0.4*\columnwidth, 0.4*\columnwidth);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It cannot even be compiled.

1. Where is wrong? How may I modify it?
2. Why cannot `text width=0.1*\columnwidth` change the size of the boxes?

Comment: Please always post complete minimal documents (starting from `\documentclass`) instead of just code snippets. That helps prevent miscommunication, and makes it easier for others to start working on a solution (answering questions is fun, figuring out the right preamble is not).

Comment: @Jake Thanks for the tip! I will learn along the way. Sorry! Question udapted.

Answer (score 5):

Without TikZ:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\innerwidth}[1]{%
  \dimexpr(\columnwidth-\numexpr#1+1\relax\fboxsep)/#1\relax
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{center}
\framebox[\columnwidth][s]{%
  \framebox[\innerwidth{3}]{Accelerometer\strut}\hfil
  \framebox[\innerwidth{3}]{Gyroscope\strut}\hfil
  \framebox[\innerwidth{3}]{Magnetometer\strut}%
}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{center}
\framebox[\columnwidth][s]{%
  \framebox[\innerwidth{2}]{Something\strut}\hfil
  \framebox[\innerwidth{2}]{Something else\strut}%
}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

With an easier interface:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{xparse,lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\boxes}{m}
 {
  \begin{center}
  \framebox[\columnwidth][s]
   { \perf_inner_boxes:n { #1 } \unskip }
  \end{center}
 }

\seq_new:N \l_perf_texts_seq
\dim_new:N \l_perf_texts_dim
\cs_new_protected:Npn \perf_inner_boxes:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_perf_texts_seq { , } { #1 }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_perf_texts_dim
   {
    (
     \columnwidth
      - 
     \int_eval:n { 1 + \seq_count:N \l_perf_texts_seq }\fboxsep
    )
    / \seq_count:N \l_perf_texts_seq
   }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_perf_texts_seq
   {
    \framebox[\l_perf_texts_dim]{##1\strut}\hfil
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\boxes{Accelerometer,Gyroscope,Magnetometer}
\lipsum[2]
\boxes{Something, Something else}
\lipsum[2]
\boxes{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have several mistakes in your code. Here is the corrected version. You can use `fit` library to draw the outer rectangle.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe,lipsum}  %% just for demo
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,positioning,fit}

\begin{document}
\noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}[block/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, anchor=south}, minimum width={width("Magnetometer")+2pt},font=\small]
    \node[block, align=left](acc) at (0,0){Accelerometer\vphantom{g}};
    \node[block, align=left,right =3em of acc](gyro) {Gyroscope};
    \node[block, align=left,right =3em of gyro](mag) {Magnetometer};
    \node[draw,rectangle,fit=(acc) (gyro)(mag)] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the boxes to occupy the entire horizontal space then do some thing like this:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe,lipsum}  %% just for demo
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,positioning,fit}

\begin{document}
\noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}[block/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, anchor=south}, minimum width=.32\columnwidth,font=\small]
    \node[block, align=left](acc) at (0,0){Accelerometer\vphantom{g}};
    \node[block, align=left,anchor=west](gyro) at (acc.east) {Gyroscope};
    \node[block, align=left,anchor=west](mag) at (gyro.east) {Magnetometer};
    \node[draw,rectangle,fit=(acc) (gyro)(mag)] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]